# CentOS python3 package difference between python36 and python36u

Tags: centos, yum, python3

I'm seeing 2 packages for Python 3 with the same name, when using search:

```
$ yum search python36
```

And I'm not sure what's the difference between them? Why have 2?

```
python36.x86_64 : Interpreter of the Python programming language
```

and

```
python36u.x86_64 : Interpreter of the Python programming language
```

(extra u in the name)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`python36u` is an alternative build provided by [IUS](http://ius.io); `python36` is an [EPEL](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) package.

`yum info python36 python36u` will show you different repos for the two, and it's likely that the IUS one has a slightly higher minor version number than the EPEL package. And just to make things even more confusing, there's also [Redhat Software Collections](https://developers.redhat.com/products/softwarecollections/overview/), which provide `rh-python36-python`.

Ultimately, it boils down to a trade-off of recent version and long support cycle, I guess.

Comment: But IUS repo has both `python36` and `python36u` packages as of 2019-12-02. See https://repo.ius.io/7/x86_64/packages/p/. If `python36` is from EPEL why IUS has it as well?